# Compile options for alsa project

Tags: c, gcc, alsa, preprocessor-directive

Question relates to the following build command which is part of a project I have inherited from a lost programmer who I can't ask to explain it. The project was based on the alsa utils 'latency' sample, which he has extended to provide other functionality. The command works on the project but I want to start stripping out all the unused junk in the project and I kind of need to understand whats going here. I can program C and use gcc in the basic sense but I don't understand the below command very well. I wonder if anyone can confirm my assumptions below and explain a couple of bits:

I have this command to build the project:

if gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../include -I../include   -Wall -pipe -g -g -O2 -MT latency.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/latency.Tpo" -c -o latency.o latency.c; then mv -f ".deps/latency.Tpo" ".deps/latency.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/latency.Tpo";  fi && /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=link gcc  -lvgagl -lvga -Wall -pipe -g -g -O2   -o latency  latency.o ../src/libasound.la

I think I understand whats going on here. Wall = warnings, pipe = irrelevant, -g = debugging stuff, -O2 optimization stuff, -MT make an object file instead of executable, and overall the first bit of the command means make a dependency list from latency.c, and also compile latency.o. The dependency file is to be called .deps/latency.Tpo.

If the first command returns success then move .deps/latency.Tpo to .deps/latency.po, if it returns failure delete .deps/latency.Tpo.

Then as long as the delete or move has succeeded, run the last bit (after the &&). Which links latency.o, ../src/libasound.la, lvgagl and lvga together into the executable latency.

Currently the project uses svgalib which I don't need it to do, so I will start by removing that, and I assume I can then remove the -lvgagl -lvga from the libtool command.

However I completely don't understand the '-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../include -I../include' portion. I know that -I is a header file search path but why is it repeated twice? And whats the DHAVE_CONFIG_H mean? And why bother making the dependency file if its not used again (I see no other references to it during the libtool step).

Comment: `-DHAVE_CONFIG_H` defines `HAVE_CONFIG_H` (`-D` sets a define).  `-I.` sets the current directory as an include path.  There's no reason to do this twice - I presume the second instance is a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of that crap is automatically generated by `automake` and `autoconf`; you can ignore it.

The duplicated include paths do not hurt, so nobody bothered to avoid them.
The `-DHAVE_CONFIG_H` is generated by `autoconf`, but not used by any code in `alsa-lib` (nor by `latency.c`).

The only non-standard options in this are the `-lvgagl -lvga` libraries, which you already know how to handle.
Everything else can be ignored when moving to another build system; the defaults will work fine.

Comment: Great thanks. Any idea why the dependency file is being generated? Maybe because other things might link to this object file once created?

Comment: It's always generated by `automake`.